# git: merge back in what I merged out

Tags: git, merge, revert

So I merged a branch, "badBranch", into my develop branch, and discovered several commits after merging that it was buggy.

I did a revert: `git revert -m 1 <commit hash of the merge>`

Worked great. Time moved on, code was written, further changes were committed on develop.

Now, having more leisure, I want to merge badBranch back into develop (or develop into it) to see if I can fix it.

But develop thinks that badBranch is in its history (I think?), so when I checkout badBranch and merge develop into it, I just get the current state of develop.

How can I force an actually merge of devleop and badBranch?

Thanks.

Comment: For the record, this is what `man git-revert` has to say: "Reverting a merge commit declares that **you will never want** the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want". Emphasis mine :)

Answer (score 6):

It is surprisingly straightforward - just revert the revert:

```
git revert <commit hash of your merge revert>
```

The howto link by Marco also offers the next solution: rebase the badBrahcn with `-no-ff` to recreate all commits (all the SHA IDs will be different) and merge it to the master.

Comment: This HOWTO might also explain you why this is the correct solution: http://schacon.github.com/git/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but what if you `checkout`ed badBranch and `merge`d in develop and then `checkout`ed develop and `merge`d in badBranch?